What are the main differences when conducting user research in the B2B space versus B2C?
As a product designer/researcher I've typically worked in the B2C space, but my current role is in a B2B SaaS org. Typically when conducting user research in the B2C space, I avoid certain questions like 'How likely are you to use this feature?' or 'How likely are you to purchase x', as users are generally poor predictors of their own behaviour.
Given users in the B2B space are subject matter experts, is this line of questioning more appropriate?

"How likely are you to use this feature" is a problematic question for a few reasons:

People are notoriously poor at predicting their future behavior. People will say they want something, and then demonstrate an unmet need for something else completely.
Using the feature might not be up to the participant. In B2B contexts, it's sometimes someone else's job, or someone else's decision on whether to use it.

The interesting thing about new B2B features is that they're usually replacing something else - another software program, a spreadsheet, a stickie system, a whiteboard. If you're still in discovery at this point (and it seems like you are), try to visit your end users in person via field research to find out what they're doing to accomplish the task today. Then have them go through the feature (via a prototype or beta version) and tell you if it could replace how someone does the task today. Why or why not? What value would you need to add in order to replace "the old way"?
There are also methods that work well in business software, like SUS assessments and the CASTLE framework, which can help you identify potential usability and desirability problems across your prototype.
Finally, when I was working in B2B, I found it useful to have an "advisory group" that I could call on to go through new ideas - friendly end user customers who are willing to take a break in their day, look at your concept, and give honest feedback. It takes a lot of strain off recruiting participants, which is much harder for business users than general consumers.

I've work on B2B applications for over 8 years. And one thing that I've realized is that the saying "the user never knows what they want" it is true over and over. I think that the best course of action is to start with some user shadowing and then create the right questions to get the best insights from the interviews. Some of the questions are what you were trying to accomplish or even ask what triggered the frustration of the user and why.
You need to change you state of mind that for some B2B users they use those tools because the system was already in place or even, they don't have a voice or the power to change or remove some of those tools in their daily lives.
Sometimes it is good that those apps are in-house tools, and you might have the option to modify or make changes that could help the user experience, however there are scenarios where these apps are third-party tools, and you can't even make suggestions to change them.

I would still avoid those questions in B2B setting.
An approach that has worked for me in the past with B2B is to ask users or interest groups to prioritise proposed features relative to each other. Assuming they are domain experts this can separate the real value-add features from the nice-to-have wish listing.
One (fun) exercise in doing this prioritisation was to give each person in a panel 100 "Development bucks" (Monopoly money) to put against any mix of features they like from about 12 features we had shortlisted. Then we would see where the money landed. The spread was not close to even. We ended up with 3 clear priorities.
It does not have to be elaborate, even a spreadsheet with features has been effective to help clients/users prioritise feature relative to each other.
